# Why do I get this as an empty opt-design?

Tags: vhdl, implementation, modelsim, vivado

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;

entity seg7ctrl is
 port
 (
 mclk : in std_logic;
 reset : in std_logic; 
 d0 : in std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
 d1 : in std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
 abcdefg : out std_logic_vector(6 downto 0);
 c : out std_logic
 );
end entity seg7ctrl;


library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
library work;
use work.seg7model_pkg.all;

architecture rtl1_c of seg7ctrl is
signal count: std_logic_vector(19 downto 0):= "00000000000000000000";
begin  
process (mclk, reset) is  
    begin
        if rising_edge(mclk) then
                count<= std_logic_vector(unsigned(count)+1);
        end if;
        c <= count(count'high);
        set_display_c(d0, abcdefg); 
        set_display_c(d1, abcdefg);
        if rising_edge(reset) then
            count<= "00000000000000000000";                 
        end if;     
end process;
end rtl1_c;

library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity self_test is
end self_test;

architecture self_test of self_test is 
component  seg7ctrl is
    port (
            mclk : in std_logic;
        reset : in std_logic;
        d0 : in std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
        d1 : in std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
        abcdefg : out std_logic_vector(6 downto 0);
        c : out std_logic);
end component seg7ctrl;

signal mclk          : std_logic := '0';
constant half_period : time := 5 ns;
signal  reset        : std_logic := '0';
signal  d0           : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0) := "0000";
signal  d1           : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0) := "0000";
signal  abcdefg      : std_logic_vector(6 downto 0) := "0000000";
signal  c            : std_logic := '0';
signal counter       : unsigned(3 downto 0) := "0000";
signal second_tick : std_logic := '0';

type rom_array_D1 is array (0 to 15) of std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);
constant rom_D1: rom_array_D1:= ( "0001", "0011", "0100", "0000", "0101", "0111", "0000", "1000", "1001", 
"0000", "1010", "0011", "0000", "1100", "0110", "0000");

type rom_array_D0 is array (0 to 15) of std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);
constant rom_D0: rom_array_D0:= ( "0010", "0100", "0000", "0000", "0110", "0011", "0000", "0110", "0000", 
"0000", "1011", "0000", "0000", "0110", "0101", "0000");

begin
    UUT: entity work.seg7ctrl(rtl1_c)
        port map (
            mclk     => mclk, 
            reset    => reset,
            d0       => d0,
            d1       => d1,
            abcdefg  => abcdefg,
            c        => c);

    mclk <= not mclk after half_period; 
    reset <= not reset after 18 sec;

    process (c) is
        variable count: integer range 0 to 100 := 0;
    begin
        if rising_edge(c) then
            d0<="ZZZZ";
            d1<=rom_D1(to_integer(unsigned(counter)));
        end if;
        if falling_edge(c) then
            d1<="ZZZZ";
            d0<=rom_D0(to_integer(unsigned(counter)));
    end if;
        if falling_edge(c) then
            count:=count+1;
        end if;
        if count=99 then 
            second_tick <= '1';
        elsif count=50 then
            second_tick <= '0';
            count:=0;
        end if;
    end process;
        
    process (second_tick, reset) is
    begin
        if rising_edge(reset) then
            counter   <= "0000";
        end if;
        if rising_edge(second_tick) then
            counter <= counter + 1;                                 
        end if;         
    end process;
end self_test;
```

First part is the entity, second is the architecture, and the third is the self test. They are in seperate files, which is why the library is above each part. I have both the architecture and the self_test as design sources in vivado. I have no problem synthesizing the design, but each time I run implementation I get this error:

```
[Place 30-494] The design is empty
Resolution: Check if opt_design has removed all the leaf cells of your design.  Check whether you 
have instantiated and connected all of the top level ports.
```

I can't find anywhere exactly what can cause this error. So it would be great if someone knows what can cause the error

Comment: No warnings or errors from mapping?  Note that there are no Xilinx primitives that have multiple edge events other than I/O cells intended for dual data rate. Reset should be evaluated as a level, either as an asynchronous or synchronous reset. There is a withdrawn standard (IEEE Std 1076.6-2004) specifying acceptable syntax for RTL Synthesis, a subset of which shown in [Xilinx User Guide 901](https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/sw_manuals/xilinx2020_2/ug901-vivado-synthesis.pdf). Otherwise this is not [on-topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Package seg7model_pkg is not provided here, apparently supplying procedure set_display_c.  The validity of your design description can't be determined without it. Has testbench self_test been mistakenly set as the top of the design (it has no ports)? You're asking your readers to peer through a keyhole without all the details in the field of view.

Comment: This question is not [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Why not? It is a specific programming problem, a commonly used software tool, specific, answerable and unique.

Comment: It's a synthesis error distinct from programming.

Comment: Did it work correctly in simulation?